JS Single Page Application - history.pushState and history.replaceState issues
I'm implementing a Single Page Application in vanilla JavaScript, and I'm stuck on history.pushState and history.replaceState issues.
This is my code:
HTML
<ul id="nav"></ul>

<div id="root"></div>

JS
const routes = {
    "home": "Home",
    "blog": "Blog",
    "contact": "Contact"
};

for (var r in routes) nav.innerHTML += `<li data-id="${r}">${routes[r]}</li>`;


const load = page => {
    page = page.replace("#", "");
    nav.querySelector(".active")?.removeAttribute("class");
    if (routes[page]) {
        nav.querySelector(`[data-id="${page}"]`).className = "active";
        fetch("pages/" + page + ".html")
            .then(res => res.text())
            .then(res => root.innerHTML = res);
        history.pushState(null, null, location.pathname + "#" + page); // ISSUE #1
        document.querySelector("title").innerText = routes[page];
    } else {
        history.replaceState(null, null, location.pathname + "#" + page); // ISSUE #2
        location.href = "errors/404.html";
    }
};


nav.onclick = e => {
    if (e.target.tagName !== "LI") return;
    load(e.target.dataset.id);
}


window.onpopstate = () => {
    load(location.hash);
}


load(location.hash || "home");

ISSUE #1 - history.pushState(null, null, location.pathname + "#" + page);
When I click on the browser's back button, it goes go back to one page only.
For instance: in the Home page, I click on Contact then on Blog, then I click on browser's back button: it takes me back to Contact page, but if I click again (and again) on that button, it doesn't take me back to Home page, stopping on Contact page.
ISSUE #2 - history.replaceState(null, null, location.pathname + "#" + page);
If the user writes a wrong URL (e.g. https://www.---.com/spa/#blogg), I want to delete that url from the browser's history, before redirecting to 404 error page. But my code doesn't do it: that URL is still in the browser's history.
How can I fix those issues?
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
P.S.: I've tested my SPA on Chrome 126, Edge 127 and Firefox 128.

How to debug small programs StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site for specific questions about actual code; “I wrote some buggy code that I can’t fix” is not a question, it’s a story, and not even an interesting story.

"Ipse dixit"...

"Any suggestions would be appreciated." My suggestion was to debug the code and add debugging details to your question. Set breakpoints history.replaceState and history.pushState, check the state before and after and find something unexpected. I would also create a separate [mcve] for each issue. That makes debugging easier.

I've debugged issue 1 for you. The problem is, that you're loading the previous history state as next history state. You're not going back in history and the previous state doesn't change. That's why you always load the same page. I think you can't use load in window.onpopstate.

Issue 2: history.replaceState(null, null, location.pathname + "#" + page); doesn't delete the current. It modifies it. You could use replaceState to replace the current wrong page with the error page or you can replace replaceState with go(-1).

I've started to write an answer with the two fixes. They solved the two issues, but while testing I've found new issues. When you go back from the error page, the router overrides the last two states. It seems like there are more issues.

Your last edit suggests that my comments didn't solve your problem. I try to explain it with a graph. Let's say, that's the history stack: page1 -> page2 -> page3. Now, you press the back button in your browser. The browser pops the stack and your code in window.onpopstate add the current page to the stack. The result: page1 -> page2 -> page2. You have to remove history.pushState from window.onpopstate.

Let's say, the history stack: page1 -> page2. Now, you enter an invalid hash. The browser pushes a new entry onto the stack and your code changes the URL to the same URL. Then, your code navigates to the error page. The new stack: page1 -> page2 -> invalid -> error. Instead, you have to remove the entry invalid. I can post you a code, that solves these two problems, but your concept has more issues and my answer would contain these issues. I'm not sure, if all the issues can be fixed or you should restart from scratch.

I need answers that can help me to find out what's wrong in my code, relating to the 2 issues above. Comments are not answers.

If you don't understand the description in the comments, you will have a hard time implementing your own SPA routing system. You should try to understand the actual problems using the comments, your debugger and the documentation without the code example in the answer.

Issue 1
The problem is, that every click on the back button pushes the previous state onto the history stack. Let's say, that's the history stack:
page1 -> page2 -> page3

Now, you press the back button in your browser. The browser pops the stack and your code in window.onpopstate pushes the current page onto the stack. The result:
page1 -> page2 -> page2.

Every other click on the back button will only load page2. You can solve it by removing
history.pushState(null, null, location.pathname + "#" + page);

from
window.onpopstate

Issue 2
The problem is, that replaceState doesn't remove the state. Let's say, the history stack is:
page1 -> page2

Now, you enter an invalid hash. The browser pushes a new entry onto the stack and your code changes the URL to the same URL. Then, your code navigates to the error page. The new stack is:
page1 -> page2 -> invalid -> error

Instead, you have to remove the entry invalid. You can replace
replaceState

with
go(-1)

Fixed code
const routes = {
    "home": "Home",
    "blog": "Blog",
    "contact": "Contact"
};

for (var r in routes) nav.innerHTML += `<li data-id="${r}">${routes[r]}</li>`;


const load = page => {
    page = page.replace("#", "");
    nav.querySelector(".active")?.removeAttribute("class");
    if (routes[page]) {
        nav.querySelector(`[data-id="${page}"]`).className = "active";
        fetch("pages/" + page + ".html")
            .then(res => res.text())
            .then(res => root.innerHTML = res);
        history.pushState(null, null, location.pathname + "#" + page); // ISSUE #1
        document.querySelector("title").innerText = routes[page];
    } else {
        history.go(-1); // ISSUE #2
        location.href = "errors/404.html";
    }
};


nav.onclick = e => {
    if (e.target.tagName !== "LI") return;
    load(e.target.dataset.id);
}


window.onpopstate = () => {
    page = location.hash.replace("#", "");
    nav.querySelector(".active")?.removeAttribute("class");
    if (routes[page]) {
        nav.querySelector(`[data-id="${page}"]`).className = "active";
        fetch("pages/" + page + ".html")
            .then(res => res.text())
            .then(res => root.innerHTML = res);
        document.querySelector("title").innerText = routes[page];
    } else {
        history.go(-1); // ISSUE #2
        location.href = "errors/404.html";
    }
}


load(location.hash || "home");


Thanks, yours is a useful help. My SPA code needs to be improved, there's no doubt, but this is a good starting point. I'm not a debugging expert, and I'm here to learn. It's a pity that my question has been closed.

@AbsoluteBeginner You should expect the close. Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform for specific questions. You've dumped your code without any debugging details and asked "How can I fix those issues?". That's usually not well received on this platform. You should learn debugging long before you write your own router. When I teach programming, I teach debugging and show profiling in the first two weeks. The debugger is the most important tool for a developer. Stack Overflow is not a platform to learn. It's a Wiki-like platform for very specific questions.
